# Libgdx render a new object

Tags: android, libgdx, rendering, render

I have 2 classes; A and B.

A is the character class, it contains every character detail (position...)
B is the class which get the A class and render. I need to create another object when I touch the screen. I got it, the class seems containing the new values but it doesn't renderize them.

```
for (A a: aa) {
    shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeType.Filled);
    shapeRenderer.setColor(Color.RED);
        shapeRenderer.circle(a.getBoundingCircle().x, a.getBoundingCircle().y, a.getBoundingCircle().radius);
    shapeRenderer.end();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

is recommended use best names.
are you sure a.getBoundingCircle() cotains the correct data, and are you sure had objects A in aa and your program join inside the for?

and i dont look b

Comment: B is the class which contain the code I posted. aa is a static list and every time A constructor run it will be added to aa (which is in class B)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, your problem is the new values dont be renderized. 
Two options:
You not are running the loop for render the objects.
Your new values are out of the screen.

When you get the position of the touch events you get the screenx and the screeny, not the game camera coordenates, and you need convert it with unproject.
For example:

```
Vector3 touchPos = new Vector3(Gdx.input.getX(), Gdx.input.getY(), 0);
camera.unproject(touchPos);
```

touchPos now is in the game coordenates.

Comment: The new object is created with the same values of the first